# How do I hide/integrate dll files using Visual Studio Installer?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, windows-installer, fody-costura

Using **Visual Studio Installer**, I created the .msi file for the WPF project and the class library for the custom action. Everything works fine, but there are many dll assembly files associated with the project in C:\Program Files (x86)\Publisher\Program.

I applied **Fody.Costura** to WPF project after researching when building the WPF project. Therefore, it is working properly in the release/debug folder of the WPF project. When I tried adding a WPF project with 'project out...' to Visual Studio Installer, regardless of Fody.Costura, dlls appeared. On the client-side, there are still dlls. Can they be hidden under the program files folder?

FYI. WPF project is built on .NET Framework 4.8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to hide dll files using the `Hidden` property. By setting this property to 'True', DLL files become hidden but still exist. If you have other ways, feel free to leave your comment.

[image]